# AWS multi-region fail-over deployment with ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Please suggest the option to deploy multi-region fail-over with ActiveMQ Artemis?
Any functionality in Artemis similar to [network of brokers](https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers)?

Comment: I can't tell if your two questions are directly related. Are you saying that the ActiveMQ "Classic" network-of-brokers functionality _does_ provide multi-region fail-over? Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: actually I referred network of brokers mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/network-of-brokers.html

Comment: Either way it's still using ActiveMQ "Classic" so the question still stands.

Comment: Is there any option to deploy AWS multi-region fail-over with ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: You need to focus your question to a single issue (e.g. multi-region fail-over **or** network-of-broker equivalency) or it's liable to be closed.